# How to get Visual Studio Online test runner to run my specflow tests?

Tags: build, msbuild, specflow, azure-devops

I have a project which builds and runs tests in Visual Studio Online.  I recently added SpecFlow the the project and wrote a bunch of scenarios, some of which run against a LocalDb database.  I was half expecting the tests to fail on VSO, but when I pushed the code up it ran all of my tests and they all passed.  When I checked the logs it seems that my Specflow tests were not run.

Is there something I have to do to get the specflow custom tool which generates the actual unit tests to run as part of the build, so that VSO will find the tests after it has built?

Can I run what are effectively integration tests in VSO, creating and destroying databases in my tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this was a bit of a D'oh moment.  VSOnline wasn't running my tests because Specflow was building NUnit test.  Changing it to build MSTest tests meant that the generated files containing the tests had the correct attributes and VSOnline recognized them and so happily built and ran them.

And using the LocalDb during the tests was fine as well, all worked like a dream.